# Using jQuery to manipulate drop down lists that are linked by css classes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Okay so I have 3 drop down lists at the top and 6 below that. The bottom 6 all have an id, (abc, def, etc). The top 3 have two of each of those ids, (abc def, mno abc, etc). Clear as mud? Okay.

So if someone selects the top ddl labeled abc def, then the quantity that they selected should be reflected in the bottom two ddls, abc and def. Easy enough.

I am having problems making it all work correctly together, especially when two of the top ddls link to the same ddl below. Like abc def and mno abc.

I created use the .change event for the .packageQuantity ddls, so that the jquery will fire when one of the top 3 ddls is changed.

Code is pasted below, I know it's something small, (at least I hope). Thanks!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".packageQuantity").change(function () {
            var currValue = $(this).attr("value");

            //create the array to hold our ids
            var ids = new Array();

            //get all of the css classes from the sender
            var classList = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);

            //loop through those classes
            $.each(classList, function (index, item) {
                if (item != "packageQuantity") {
                    //store just the actual ids
                    ids[item] = 0;
                    //ids.push(item);
                }
            });

            //get all of the package ddls
            var srcs = $(".packageQuantity");

            //something to keep the total value in 
            var total = 0

            //loop through all of the package ddls
            $.each(srcs, function (index, item) {
                //get all of the classes for the current ddl
                var itemClasses = $(item).attr("class").split(/\s+/);

                //loop through the classes for the current ddl
                $.each(itemClasses, function (childIndex, childItem) {

                    //all we want are the classes that are ids
                    if (childItem != "packageQuantity") {

                        //lets see if any of these ids are in the sender too
                        if (ids[childItem] > -1) {

                            //add the current value of the ddl to the total
                            total = parseInt($(item).attr("value"), 10) + total;

                            ids[childItem] = total;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            //loop through and remove the value of the current ddl
            //from the totals
            $.each(ids, function (index, item) {
                var temp = ids[item];
                ids[item] = temp - currValue;
            });

            //get the price drop down lists
            var ddls = $(".priceQuantity");

            //loop through price ddls 
            $.each(ddls, function (index, item) {
                //get the classes for the current ddl
                var itemClasses = $(item).attr("class").split(/\s+/);

                //loop through the classes
                $.each(itemClasses, function (childIndex, childItem) {

                    //all we want are the classes that are ids                        
                    if (childItem != "priceQuantity") {

                        //is this ddl one of the ones we want to set?
                        if (ids[childItem] > -1) {
                            //set the total value for the price ddl
                            alert(ids[childItem]);
                            $(item).val(ids[childItem]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });               //close of ready function
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            abc def
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackage1" runat="server" CssClass="packageQuantity abc def" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            mno abc
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackage2" runat="server" CssClass="packageQuantity mno abc" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            mno pqr
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackage3" runat="server" CssClass="packageQuantity mno pqr" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            abc
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice1" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity abc" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            def
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice2" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity def" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ghi
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice3" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity ghi" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            jkl
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice4" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity jkl" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            mno
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice5" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity mno" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            pqr
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrice6" runat="server" CssClass="priceQuantity pqr" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please reduce the ammount of code so we can understand it? Just remove anything that isn't related to your problem.

Comment: Done. The jQuery is where my problems are. I just had the c# in there so that people could easily reproduce it all; sorry about that. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have been at this going on 13 hours.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still too much to grasp =\ If you can, isolate your problem in http://www.JSFiddle.net and post a link.

Comment: Yeah sorry man, I don't know where my problem is, or if I'm even following the right path. Either way fiddle [link.](http://jsfiddle.net/xG55w/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle. It is pretty straight forward once you pull all the possible options into a distinct list.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5tn/1/

```
(function(){
    var values = [];

    function initValues() {
        $("select.priceQuantity").each(function(){
            values = values.concat(this.className.split(" "));      
        });
        values = $.unique(values).filter(function(v){ return v != "priceQuantity" });
    }

    function updateValues(){
        var i = values.length;
        while(i--){
            var n = 0;
            $("select.packageQuantity." + values[i])
                .each(function(idx,el){ n += parseInt($(el).val(), 10) } );
            $("select.priceQuantity." + values[i]).val(n);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(initValues);
    $(".packageQuantity").change(updateValues);
    $(".priceQuantity").change(updateValues); // what is supposed to happen here?

})();
```

Comment: Wow man thanks. That is a lot more straightforward than I was doing it.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working in IE8. It's throwing an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the load of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: I expect it is the `className` call, but I have no intention of installing IE8 to debug, sorry. You could use a jQuery approach like `$(this).attr("class")` instead if that is the case.